# Applying a DataTexture to a programmatically generated Mesh in three.js

Tags: three.js

**The actual question:**

Do I need to set more than `faceVertexUvs[0]` to texture a Material on a Mesh?  I'm not sure how to get rid of the `glDrawElements` error.  I have tried using different Materials such as `MeshPhongMaterial` and `MeshLambertMaterial`, but frankly I'm not sure what the difference is.  I've also tried calling `computeVertexNormals()` and `computeTangents()` on my underlying geometry. The firehose approach is not working here..

**Previous description**

I am building a mesh at runtime using a geometry that starts out as a triangle-tesselated plane.  I deform the mesh by updating the z coordinates of the vertices periodically.  This all works fine, but I'm having problems using a Material with a DataTexture.

I get this error:

```
glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range elements in attribute 0
```

I think that this message means that it cannot find the UV layer for my geometry, but this is not for lack of trying to insert the vectors.  Here is my code that loads faces into my Geometry called `model`

```
for (j=0; j<vh-1; j++) {
for (i=0; i<vw-1; i++) {

    var a = j*vw+i;
    var b = (j+1)*vw+i;
    var c = (j*vw+i+1);
    var d = (j+1)*vw+i+1;

    model.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(a,b,c) );
    model.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(c,b,d) );

    model.faceVertexUvs[0].push( [ new THREE.Vector2(0,0),
                   new THREE.Vector2(1,1),
                   new THREE.Vector2(1,0) ] );
    model.faceVertexUvs[0].push( [ new THREE.Vector2(0,0),
                   new THREE.Vector2(1,1),
                   new THREE.Vector2(1,0) ] );

}
}
```

I then add this model, along with a material to a faceMesh, which is in turn added to the scene:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
var faceMesh = new THREE.Mesh(model, material);
```

It is later in the code that I add a texture to this material, and this is when the above gL errors show up (in the Chrome javascript console)

```
material.map = new THREE.DataTexture(new Uint8Array(bytes, rgbByteIdx), 
                     inputW, inputH, THREE.RGBFormat);

material.needsUpdate = true;
```

I have tried using `faceUVs` in addition to `faceVertexUVs` when building the Geometry.  Perhaps I need to use something other than MeshBasicMaterial for this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, after much trial and error.

The problem here is that I initially set my `MeshBasicMaterial` with no texture.  After adding a texture and setting the `needsUpdate` flag for this material, it proceeded to throw the gL errors.

By initially creating my Material with a specific texture (using `ImageUtils.generateDataTexture`), the later addition of a texture is accepted by the system, the errors go away, and I am successfully drawing my picture on the mesh.

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.generateDataTexture(inputW, inputH, initColor );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture });
var faceMesh = new THREE.Mesh(model, material);
```